# SQL - How to count items from other tables?

Tags: sql

I have a table name BRANDS.  I have another table named MODELS.  The tables are like this:

```
BRANDS
BrandID // pk
BrandName

MODELS
ModelID // pk
BrandID // fk
ModelName
```

Each brand has zero to many brands associated with it. Each model can be associated with only one brand.

My output should look something like this:

```
Brand             # of Models
Goodyear               5
Chevy                  19
Toyota                 7
```

The query I use to get the models looks like this:

```
SELECT   BrandID, BrandName
FROM     Brands
ORDER BY BrandName
```

My count query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(BrandID) AS TotalBrands
FROM Brands
WHERE SiteID = ?
```

I have a few other things that I need to count also, from other tables.

Can you get me started on how to count the items from the MODELS table?

Thanks!!!

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ANSER

I used all of your answers as hints to help me get what I needed. This is the real query.

```
        SELECT      S.SiteID,
                    S.SiteName,
                    COUNT(BrandID) AS TotalBrands
        FROM        Sites S
                    LEFT JOIN Brands B
                        ON S.SiteID = B.SiteID
        GROUP BY    S.SiteID, S.SiteName
```

Comment: Did you mean: "Each brand has zero to many **models** associated with it"?

Comment: If your ORDER BY clause is returning "Goodyear", "Chevy", "Toyota" in ascending order you may need to level your server.

Comment: @Evik All the provided answers look valid to me. Please mark the one you think is most suitable as "answered" (and possibly upvote others that you deem useful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Brands.BrandID, COUNT(*)
FROM Brands INNER JOIN Models ON Brands.BrandID=Models.BrandID
GROUP BY Brands.BrandID
```

Comment: Your answer was the closest to the one I am most familiar with. It would have been nice to get an explanation though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT BrandID, COUNT(ModelID)
FROM BRANDS JOIN MODELS USING (BrandID)
GROUP BY BrandID
```

This will **not** include BRANDS with 0 MODELS. If you want them too, you'll need LEFT JOIN.

*(Oracle syntax, you may need to use `ON` instead of `USING` for other databases)*

Comment: `USING` is not universal, and it's actually a pretty bad idea in general not to explicitly specify your `JOIN` fields.

Comment: @ JNK Agreed that the `USING` is not universal. Why do you think it is a bad idea "not to explicitly specify your JOIN fields"?

Comment: imagine you are used to letting the RDBMS decide the fields on both sides for you.  And imagine you have two tables with `id, col1` and `id, FK_ID`.  If you are `USING (id)` you will `JOIN` on the incorrect fields.

Comment: @JNK Unless I actually want `ON T1.id = T2.id`! When crafting a query, I have to think about what fields I need to match. If they have same the same name I can use `USING`, if they don't I'll use `ON`. I don't see how choosing one or another allows me to stop thinking about what I need to do. BTW, your example is fairly contrived and properly named data model will not have such duplicates.

Comment: it's common to have an `id` per table, not contrived.  And `USING` can lead to bad habits/assumptions is my point.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.BrandName AS 'Brand',
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Models AS M WHERE M.BrandID = B.BrandID ) as '# Of Models'
  FROM Brands AS B
  ORDER BY B.BrandName
```

This will include brands which have zero models.  You can filter them out in a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE exists ( SELECT 42 FROM Models WHERE BrandID = B.BrandID )
```